# SSL Handshake exception in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am invoking an API command (**nifi-api/access/token**) to get the access token. But i am getting error  like this `java.net.SSLHandShakeException` unable to find  valid certification path  for requested target. we have LDAP configured in NiFi Cluster and i am able to login to NiFi UI using my credentials. I have started exploring the NiFi rest API for the first time. Any help would be appreciated !!

(P.S  I want to use   rest api  by codes and native  processors  ( i can  do in simple  nifi  which i have on my  desktop) how can i make  my task on nifi  with kerberso  autentification?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: it  trows  exception like  this PKIX building path:unable  to  find  valid  certificate  path to requested target

Comment: I have   token bearer  but   don't  know  how to add  it  to my request

Comment: export public certificate  chain for your server url: you can use browser - information about certificate. add this certificate into truststore: you can use keytool from java jdk. use truststore to connect from client to server.

Comment: how can i   import  this  certificate   from browser?

Comment: I found  it  ......

Comment: for   some   reason  i can't  export  certificate and  see  it's  authority is there any way  i can  use insecure  connection  to use  rest  api  commands  inside nifi?

Comment: no way. you have to export certificate. just use browser. in google chrome press `f12` key, select `Security` tab, `View Certificate` button, and press `copy to file` on `details` tab.

Comment: I have  added it inside jre\lib\security  how can i import it in nifi?

Answer (score 1):

import certificate into truststore.jks using keytool. then in the invokehttp processor use `SSL Context Service` that should point to your truststore.jks

Comment: should i  have  add  only trustore.jks inside ssl  context  service parameters? now it  shows me that  can't read   my jks  file

Comment: probably because you provided not a jks file.. how did you create it?

Comment: keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias root -file test.cer -keystore cacerts.jks

Comment: i used  this and  have jks  file  now

Comment: is  it possible  that  ssl  certificate in nifi  is coorupted  or malformed or  it is my fault

Comment: if keytool can reed it (keytool -list ...) then the jks file is ok. so just check the parameters of SSL Context Service. you have to set `Truststore Filename`, `Truststore Password` , and `Truststore Type=JKS`. and what error do you have? PS: set the password for your truststore.

Comment: but ssl context service shows me: that  truststore  file validated  agains cacerts.jks it is invalid  because fail  doesn;t exist or can;t be read

Comment: i have  filepath like this  : C:/Users/user/Desktop/cacerts.jks  should  i change it to C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\lib\security (p.s  i have set  password on jks  file too)

Comment: I have changed  location to C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_144/lib/cacerts.jks but it wasn't  helpful

Comment: `file does not exist` - check that you specified full file path to jks. does not matter where it is located

Comment: I have  replaced  it  with C:/Windows/System32/cacerts.jks nohing  has changed

Comment: it should be a server related path. check that jks file placed on server, and nifi server has access to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153223/discussion-between-sally-tkhilaishvili-and-daggett).